# What is this small insect with a rounded brown head burrowing into my rhododendron?

Tags: identification, pests, insects, rhododendrons

I caught this bug burrowing into the trunk of my rhododendron, and I persuaded it to exit its home.

[image: enter link description here]

Here's a close up of said worm.

[image: close up of worm]

I can't imagine it being other than damaging to my tree. Anyone know what it is?  The location is Wellington, New Zealand.

Edit: the bark had been damaged by my plastic rubbish bin rubbing against it and I believe this is why some beetle laid its egg here. I removed the [frass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frass) before taking the picture, and I admit I did use a Philips screwdriver to encourage the woodworm to leave its new home in my tree.  The hole is about 4 mm (.15 in) in diameter so I think it's too big for a rhododendron borer which I'm not even sure we have in NZ.  The holes of the two tooth borer are said to be oval but this one seems quite round.

Comment: Hi Graham! I know nothing about these things, but spent an hour searching the internet, and I can't figure it out! (You've probably already done that!) I agree that it doesn't seem to be a rhododendron borer. Do you have any June bugs or similar beetles? Some of their larvae have rounder heads with spiky fur, and similar bodies, like the [stag beetle](http://www.pbase.com/lejun/image/153759805), although I don't think that's it!  Some wood borers are common to azalea and rhododendron. [This NZ site](https://www.rhododendron.org.nz/) is worth a look. Sorry I couldn't help you!

Comment: Send a photo to the bug man.  I think his email would be ruud@newstalkzb.co.nz

Answer (score 3):

A borer, don't know the specific one. Almost any plant can be attacked . They are difficult to kill with poison ( Lindane). It is usually more practical to kill them with something like a wire; normally only one or a few.

Comment: Don't borers eat dead wood?

Comment: I have seen them in live trees - oaks, pines, birch, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something we have here, a Leopard Moth (Zeuzera pyrina) however the location information I have is quite wrong and I've never seen anything like this before munching into a Rhodo? the best thing is to prune out the affected wood and burn it. keep an eye out for anymore- just try to keep the site clean and remove any dead material around the parent plant. I wouldn't bother spraying for one occurrence.

Comment: But not found in New Zealand so it's probably something else.